# While using ssh with Gui script it is giving error

Tags: linux

When I'm using the line below in script:

```
ssh -Y user@host /home/user/xxx  (xxx is gui script will open GUI window)
```

It is giving me error as below:

```
xauth: not found.
stty: : Not a typewriter
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X connection to 10.100.2.23:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

One solution I found on the net was to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and set:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

But I can't open `sshd_config` file:

```
grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
grep: can't open /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

But if I run this command:

```
ssh -Y user@host`
```

After reached at the new host if I try to execute:

```
xxx  (xxx is gui script will open GUI window)
```

It works fine. I have to use it in script only. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` must be edited as root. If you don't have the administration rights on the ssh server, then you should ask the administrator to modify the configuration.

Don't forget to have the ssh service restarted after having modified the configuration file.